# Load svg icon sprites externally?

Tags: html, css, icons, css-sprites

Is there any way to load an svg defs icon sprite collection externally (using a reference or url) without having to paste the svg definitions at the beginning of your html page?

Comment: See [**this**](https://css-tricks.com/svg-use-external-source/) and [**this**](https://github.com/jonathantneal/svg4everybody)

Comment: An external library that sniffs the ua and makes ajax requests for svg's later injected into the page? Ouch!  Back to using icon fonts.

Comment: You asked, can't help if you don't like the answer :)